# Android button click next display of listview of data in JSON

Tags: android, json, listview

hi can you help me how to display the next 10 data in json by click the next button. i have 50 data and i want to display first 10. Then when I click the next button, 11-20 will display in listview. Ill post my code below and i dont have any idea how to do it. Also when i click previous button it will go back to previous listview which is 1-10. Thanks!

```
    doctordata = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(d);
        jsonArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("Doctors");
        int arraylength = jsonArray.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < arraylength; i++) {
            Map<String, String> doctormap = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
            doctor = jsonChildNode.optString("Name").toString();
            specialty = jsonChildNode.optString("Specialty").toString();
            doctormap.put("name", doctor);
            doctormap.put("specialty", specialty);
            doctordata.add(doctormap);
        }
        String[] from = {"name", "specialty"};
        int[] views = {R.id.doctorlist_name, R.id.doctorlist_specialty,};
        final SimpleAdapter myadapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, doctordata, R.layout.doctor_list, from, views);
        list.setAdapter(myadapter);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Add to your question the json you are expecting please

Comment: You want the 10 first items from `doctordata` ? Or `jsonArray` ?

Comment: @jipr311 the name and specialty have 50 data and i want to display the first 10, then when i click the next button, 11-20 will display and so on

Comment: jsonArray @Maloubobola sorry if you are confused in my question im new only and i want to try the json

Answer (score 0):

Define a class called Doctors, with fields String name and String Specialty, and add the Doctors to a list that you can iterate or convert to Array.

```
class Doctors {
        private final String specialty;
        private final String name;
        public Doctors (){
            specialty= "Spe1";
            name = "name";
        }
    }

public String convertToJson(){
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        return  gson.toJson(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are several ways to do what do you want to achieve. I will explain you how I would do it:

Firts, in the **doctorData** arraylist you have all the items (50 items) that you need to show.

Create a **partialDoctorData** arraylist and assing to it only the first 10 items from doctorData, ok? and add this new arraylist to the SimpleAdaper.

So you will need to do instead of your code:

```
final SimpleAdapter myadapter = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, **partialDoctorData**, R.layout.doctor_list, from, views);
list.setAdapter(myadapter);
```

So when the user click in the next button, you can clean the partialDoctorData content, add from the 11-20 items from the original doctorData arrayList and and and directly call to the

```
 myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

(you don't have to repeat the step to create a new SimpleAdapter, only changing the values of the arraylist and calling to this method, the content of the list is going to be updated with the content of the partialDoctorData)

Try ;)

Comment: do you have example?sorry sir dont know how to start since i only google the basic

Comment: but you don't really need an example, it is really simple, you need 2 arraysLists, one with the 50 items, and another with only 10. The last one is the one is going to be inside of the adapter when you create, and everytime that you wish change the content of the listview, in your case clicking a button, change the content of the second array and only call to the method myadapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: ahh okay i thought i will remove the doctorData. thank you btw

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

[Android ListView with Load More Button](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-listview-with-load-more-button/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination when 10 items will be loaded after that you will call agin api to get next 10 items